# Cannot find method moneyToMicros((class))

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I'm trying to programmatically change the max cpc with an AdWords script, but I'm getting an error. The console just says "Cannot find method moneyToMicros((class))". I cannot find any documentation about this error or any other posts about this anywhere. Was wondering if anyone knew how to get around this. Here's a small snippet of the code where the error occurs (error occurs on the line where setKeywordMaxCpc() is called):

```
while (adGroupIterator.hasNext())
{
  var adGroup = adGroupIterator.next();
  var adGroupName = adGroup.getName();
  if (adGroupRegex.test(adGroupName))
  {
    if (adGroup.isPaused())
    {
      adGroup.enable();
      adGroup.setKeywordMaxCpc(bidModifier);
    }
  }

  else
  {
    adGroup.pause();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I've just resolved it!
I was passing the value "null" to the function .setKeywordMaxCpc();
So I think you need to check if the variable bidModifier is null before you execute the function .setKeywordMaxCpc(bidModifier );

In my case I was using the value keyword.getFirstPageCpc() to set my bid, and in some words that value is null.

Comment: I had the same issue and this error is related to sending in a 'null' value into the update request. I would reccomend doing a quick check before the call. I would also recommend a try/catch in there to better trap the error and be made aware of other errors.

if (bidModifier) {
adGroup.setKeywordMaxCpc(bidModifier);
}